# Duplicates on Insert into & unique constraint SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I've got the following problem whilst running an Insert Statement:

I got 2 tables: a temporary table with Customer order information imported via SSIS (order-csv-import) and the main Customer table (Customer).

One of the tasks in the job I created is to create the customer, if not yet existing:

```
insert into dbo.[Customer] (FirstName, LastName, PostalAddress1, PostalAddress2,
                            State_Prov, City, ZIPPostalCode, Country,
                            Email, BYear, BMonth, BDay, Gender,
                            CheckInDate, Check_In_by,  Comments)
   Select distinct 
       billing_first_name,
       billing_last_name,
       billing_address_1,
       billing_address_2,
       PADI_State,
       billing_city,
       bil ling_postcode,
       PADI_Country,
       billing_email,
       BYear,
       BMonth,
       BDay,
       Gender,
       arrival_date,
       '0',
       customer_note
   from 
       dbo.[orders-csv-import] OCI
   where 
       not exists (select 1 
                   from dbo.Customer TCI 
                   where TCI.LastName = OCI.billing_last_name
                     and TCI.FirstName = OCI.billing_first_name
                     and TCI.BDay = OCI.BDay
                     and TCI.BMonth = OCI.BMonth
                     and TCI.BYear = OCI.BYear)
```

This works perfectly, and existing customers in the `Customer` table are ignored. The problem started when I got the same customer making two bookings in a row. Now my temporary source table got the same customer twice, and it throws me an error as I got a Unique Key Constraint on the `Customer` table with the combination of First Name, Last Name, Birth Day, Month and Year.

> Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Line 3
>   Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'constraint_Unique_CUSTOMER_EXISTS'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Customer'.

I looked into it, but all solutions I could find are based on identifying duplicates on insert in the target table.

In my case I would need to eliminate one of the two entries in my source table.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Window Function` to remove the duplicates

To avoid duplicate's based on the UQ you have created you need to use window function

```
Row_number() OVER(partition BY billing_first_name, billing_last_name, 
                              bday, 
                              bmonth ,byear 
                                ORDER BY bmonth, byear ) Rn
```

Make the select query as sub select and in outer query you can filter out the duplicates by checking `where Rn=1`. Insert should be like

```
INSERT INTO dbo.[customer] 
            (firstname, 
             lastname, 
             postaladdress1, 
             postaladdress2, 
             state_prov, 
             city, 
             zippostalcode, 
             country, 
             email, 
             byear, 
             bmonth, 
             bday, 
             gender, 
             checkindate, 
             check_in_by, 
             comments) 
SELECT DISTINCT billing_first_name, 
                billing_last_name, 
                billing_address_1, 
                billing_address_2, 
                padi_state, 
                billing_city, 
                billing_postcode, 
                padi_country, 
                billing_email, 
                byear, 
                bmonth, 
                bday, 
                gender, 
                arrival_date, 
                check_in_by, 
                customer_note 
FROM   (SELECT billing_first_name, 
                        billing_last_name, 
                        billing_address_1, 
                        billing_address_2, 
                        padi_state, 
                        billing_city, 
                        billing_postcode, 
                        padi_country, 
                        billing_email, 
                        byear, 
                        bmonth, 
                        bday, 
                        gender, 
                        arrival_date, 
                        '0' check_in_by, 
                        customer_note, Row_number() 
                          OVER( 
                            partition BY billing_first_name, billing_last_name, 
                          bday, 
                          bmonth ,byear 
                            ORDER BY bmonth, byear ) Rn 
        FROM   dbo.[orders-csv-import] OCI 
        WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                           FROM   dbo.customer TCI 
                           WHERE  TCI.lastname = OCI.billing_last_name 
                                  AND TCI.firstname = OCI.billing_first_name 
                                  AND TCI.bday = OCI.bday 
                                  AND TCI.bmonth = OCI.bmonth 
                                  AND TCI.byear = OCI.byear)) A 
WHERE  rn = 1
```

Comment: mmmh ... literally just copied and pasted ... it throws me this one:
Msg 8155, Level 16, State 2, Line 64
No column name was specified for column 15 of 'A'.

Comment: @user2301990 did you check the complete code blindly don't comment I have used Window function to remove the duplicates in sub select and the bug is because i missed `check_in_by` alias in sub select You should be able to fix these bugs. Updated the answer

Comment: sorry, was busy with other stuff - it works fine once I actually used a valid column name - so far I only had a '0' as value for check_in_by ... so I just changed that to a column name and it works perfect.
Thanks and sorry for commenting without checking ;)